# Can I ask about fairy tales and folk tales here? Would they be considered "fantasy"?

Tags: discussion

Can I ask about fairy tales and folk tales here? Would they be considered "fantasy" or something else? Fairy tales may fit the fantasy genre because of the magical things, and many fairy tales have fairies or magical creatures. Folk tales, on the other hand, may be a bit tricky because they are essentially traditional stories that may resemble fairy tales. Now, if folk tales had been accepted here, then it wouldn't be so far-fetched to post biblical stories, or do biblical stories have their own separate genre called "religious literature"?

Comment: Re: biblical stories, it was covered on a couple of other meta questions. Search meta site for "religion", "religious" or "bible" or "biblical"

Answer (score 16):

Fairy Tales- Sure, why not.

Folk Lore- Probably not, but possibly. If you can make a good argument for it being fantasy, then go for it.

Religious stories- There's a ban for considering any religious text as "Fantasy" on this site, however, stories based on religious texts can be discussed.

Comment: I know we reference J.K. Rowling's *Tales of Beedle the Bard* quite frequently when answering *Harry Potter* questions -- those are fairy tales that also contain lore for Potterverse. I think it's an *essential* book to be able to reference when trying to answer some of the more complex *Harry Potter* questions, such as questions about wandlore, for example.

Comment: @Slytherincess That's a little different, since those are in-universe fairy tales for a work that is definitely fantasy. I assume we're talking about real world fairy and folk tales here.